# Rationale for breaking this answer into a function using Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I was doing a coderbyte problem earlier today and honestly was very happy that I was able to break it down and complete it without looking at any answers that anyone else completed.  However, after completing it, I realized that with the way I did it, I did not really build any functions. I just kept calling a former variable. My question is really, is it necessary to use a function when answering a problem? Looking at the big picture, what would be the pro's of converting an answer like mine into a function ( or a pair of functions)

I basically took a number that represented full minutes, and broke it down into hours and minutes. I think it should be easy to follow.

```
var num = 400;
var hourdivide = ( num / 60 );
var digits = hourdivide.toString().split('');
var hour = digits[0]
var almost = 60 * digits[0]
var minutes = num - almost

console.log( "you have  " + hour + " hours and " + minutes + " minutes left" )
```

Comment: There's many reasons, but one important point is that if you created a function with a descriptive name I would have a quicker time understanding what your code does. Right now I have to read through everything.

Comment: Since this code works and your question is about potential code improvement, you could consider asking this question _instead_ on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Just don't cross-post on both Stack Overflow and Code Review.  See also what is [on-topic for Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: For what it's worth, that's not a very good way of doing the problem, function or no function. It won't work when the number of hours is greater than 9, for example.

Comment: The rationale for doing something in production programming is different from a coding puzzle.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't think he's asking for a review of this code. He's asking a more general question about whether or not one should put code like this into a function or just run it at top-level.

Comment: If I _were_ reviewing this code, I'd give it a grade of C.

Comment: @Barmar it's certainly not a problem for this question to be here.  I just wanted to make sure the OP was aware of all valid options.  I would personally have asked this on Code Review.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm not sure it belongs on any SE site. It's about programming style, which is opinion-based, and not a good fit for our Q/A model.

Comment: As Pointy pointed out, this will not work in some (many?) cases (wrapped in function or not), maybe OP should try with num=900, or 600...

Comment: @Barmar it is on-topic as a _specific_ best practice (for extracting functions) at code review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rationale for breaking code into a function is often reusability and composability.

Let's look at how that that code could be turned into a useful function

```
function minutesToHours(num) {
  var hourdivide = ( num / 60 );
  var digits = hourdivide.toString().split('');
  var hour = digits[0]
  var almost = 60 * digits[0]
  var minutes = num - almost;

  return [hour, minutes];
}
```

This function now returns an array with two values in, that we could use in any project we wanted.

---

We might not always want it to print that same message, turning it into a function allows us to control that outside of the actual logic ([separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)).

```
var time = minutesToHours(404);
console.log("you have", time[0], "hours and", time[1], " minutes left");
```

Using a function instead has allowed you to parameterize your code, meaning that the same few lines of logic can be used to calculate results for any given input. This is particularly useful if you start to use loops in your code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log(minutesToHours(i));
}
```

The alternative would have been far less succinct.

---

Another benefit is the composability which comes with fact that turning code into functions is a form of standardisation. We **know** that we will always get an array from this function. It will **always** have hours in position 0 and minutes in position 1.

We can use this to write other functions that expect that style output.

```
function printTime(time, divider) {
  var hours = time[0],
      minutes = time[1];

  return [hours, divider, minutes].join('');
}
```

Now we can do things like:

```
var time = minutesToHours(4041);
printTime(time, ':'); // prints "67:21"
```

Answer (score 0):

A "pro" to making this a function would be that every time you want to convert from minutes to hours:minutes, you would not have to copy the entire code again, you would be able to do something like `convert(550)`.

Like such:

```js
function convert(minutes){
  var hourdivide = ( minutes / 60 );
  var digits = hourdivide.toString().split('');
  var hours = digits[0];
  var almost = 60 * digits[0];
  var minutes = minutes - almost;
  return "Hours: "+hours+" Minutes: "+minutes;
  }

alert(convert(550));
alert(convert(82));
alert(convert(223));
```